# How do I get Visual Studio to prompt for a password for each SSIS project in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

TL;DR: Visual Studio is not letting me enter the passwords for each of my projects, but is throwing warnings and preventing me from using sensitive data without reconfiguring all the sensitive fields in each project every time.

The Problem:

I have solution *ProductionStuff* with projects *ProjA*, *ProjB*, and *ProjC*, each of which has a Project.params file with sensitive data and each of which has EncryptSensitiveWithPassword enabled and set with a password.

There are some SSIS packages in each of the projects, each of which has EncryptSensitiveWithPassword enabled with the password set to the same password as that of its Project.

When I open the ProductionStuff.sln file, Visual Studio opens, prompts me to enter the password for *ProjA*, loads *ProjA*, then the prompt for the password for *ProjB* flashes and instantly disappears, the soltution loads *ProjB*, then the same happens for *ProjC*.  Now, when everything finally comes up, there are several warnings:

```
Warning loading ProjB.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because 
  the password was not specified or not correct.  Project load will ...
Warning loading ProjB.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt sensitive data in a project with
  a password.  The password was not specified, or is not correct. ...
Warning loading ProjC.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because 
  the password was not specified or not correct.  Project load will ...
Warning loading ProjC.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt sensitive data in a project with
  a password.  The password was not specified, or is not correct. ...
```

How do I get it to prompt me for each password every time I open the solution?

Other info:

Visual Studio: 15.8.4

SSDT: 15.1.61808.07020

SSAS: 14.0.1016.285

SSIS: (No version listed despite being installed)

SSRS: 14.0.1016.285

Projects are being deployed to SQL Server 2012 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the password dialog window is still there, but it's out of focus. I have seen the same on mine. I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring it back in focus to enter the password.